# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (Swift & Parse)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

When I go to just post text alone this error occurs. But when I post an `UIImage` with text it works fine.

```
func postFeed(text: String, image: UIImage?) {

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint, error) in

        if let geopoint = geopoint {

            let object = PFObject(className: "UserFeed")

            object.setValue(text, forKey: "post")

            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)

            let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData) //ERROR HERE <<

            object.setValue(imageFile, forKey: "imageFile")

            object.setValue(geopoint, forKey: "location")

            if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {

                object.setValue(user, forKey: "fromUser")

            }

            object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    //println("Success object saved to parse")

                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(postNotification, object: success)

                }

            })

        }

    }

}
```

Here is where I assign the picture uploaded to parse to the `UIImageView`. Somehow I need to only get the image posted by that User ID and assign it to the `UIImageView`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TalesTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    if let posts = posts {

        let object = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.tableLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 16)

        cell.tableLabel?.text = object["post"] as? String

        cell.tableLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        object["imageFile"]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                cell.tableImage.image = image

            }
        })

    }

    return cell
}
```

I'm lost, I've tried so many thing yet failed each time, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use conditional un-wrapping for the image object also.

Replace:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)
let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
object.setValue(imageFile, forKey: "imageFile")
```

With:

```
if let image = image
{
   let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)
   let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
   object.setValue(imageFile, forKey: "imageFile")
}
```

Comment: It worked but now the image is getting assigned to the post above it when the post is deleted on parse.

Comment: @JoeMancini: How are you deleting the post ? Can you add that code in this comment section?

Comment: I used the parse website to delete the row.

Comment: it also sets a new post without an image attached with the same image I just posted before in the last post.

Comment: I edited my original if that could help at all. Thanks!